# How to set destructor for a class with unique_ptr<double[]>. the instance is created by make_unique()

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a class, the member variable is `std::unique_ptr<double[]>`. Initializing this variable is always done by `make_unique<double[]>(size)`.
But I do not know how to write code for destructor for this member variable

I know `std::unique_ptr` has a method `get_deleter()`, but when I look at the docs, it just provide self-defined delete. I do some research about similiar examples. But all of them are about new `className()`, not `make_unique()`.

the verison of cpp is c++17

My code

```
class test{
public:
     test(int size) : size_{size}, arr_{make_unique<double[]>( size )} {}

     ~test(){
         // how to destroy arr_
     }
private:
    int size_;

    std::unique_ptr<double[]> arr_;
};
```

I do not know how to start. I know there is a keyword `delete`, but I think it is not useful in this case.

Comment: default is fine :-) you have nothing to do.

Comment: so "~test() = default; " should be enough?

Answer (score 7):

Do not write a destructor at all.

`std::unique_ptr` will do the cleanup for you correctly, and indeed that's the main point of using a `unique_ptr` in the first place.

Whenever possible, follow the [Rule Of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero): Use smart pointers and containers correctly, and don't declare any destructor, copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment, or move assignment. (See the link for discussion of the main exception, declaring an interface's destructor virtual, and deleting or defaulting the rest.)

Comment: so "~test() = default; " should be enough?

Comment: Don't even type that much. If you do, that disables the automatic declarations of the move constructor and move assignment operator, which would be useful for that class. If you really want to be explicit about it, you'd want to define all three: `~test() = default; test(test&&) = default; test& operator=(test&&) = default;`

Answer (score 1):

> I do not know how to write code for destructor for this member variable

Nothing in particular needs to be written in order to destroy any member variable. All member objects as well as base class objects are destroyed by all destructors after the body of the destructor has been executed.

There is no need to do anything in the body of the destructor, and therefore the implicitly generated destructor is sufficient for the class.